# Why the regexp give me the compile time panic error in golang?

Tags: go

I made a program for validate the names of the users but regexp will give me the compile time panic error why it so happen and how to resolve it below is the program I'm using :-

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "regexp"
)

func main() {
  var arr [5]string
  arr[0] = "O’max"
  arr[1] = "O’sdf"
  arr[2] = "dsf’max"
  arr[3] = "dsfrewwerx"
  arr[4] = "ewrwerwerwerwr’max"
  var validName = regexp.MustCompile("^[a-zA-ZÀ-ž\x7f-\xff\u00c0-\u017e0-9-_&$.,'`()!/ ]*$")
  for i := 0; i < len(arr); i++ {
    if !validName.MatchString(arr[i]) {
        fmt.Println(arr[i])
    }
  }
}
```

Error

> panic: regexp: Compile("^[a-zA-ZÀ-ž\u007f-\xffÀ-ž0-9-*&$.,'`()!/ ]*$"): error parsing regexp: invalid UTF-8:`�À-ž0-9-*&$.,'`()!/ ]*$`

Any body tell me How i will make a regrex for the validating the names of the users below is the playground link

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/THFeFzG-tKh)

Answer (score 3):

use

```
^[\\p{L}0-9-_&$.,'\x60()!/ ]*$
```

As your regexp, where the "letters" including non ascii are the \p{L} class and the backtick is a \x60

Comment: it give me the error of the `unknown escape sequence`

Comment: sorry missed a backslash